# HitTest only for chape inside arc

Tags: flutter, automatic-ref-counting, hittest

[Please help. I will hitTest to return true if i'm inside my custom shape in my Arc. How can i calculate Geometry for my arc so that i get true from hitTest ONLY if i'm clicking inside my chape of the arc. I stuck with this.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ac4o8.png)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ac4o8.png)

Comment: use `Path` API, both for painting and hit testing, `Path` has `contains` method - the docs say: *"Tests to see if the given point is within the path"*

Comment: How can i use Path with Arc , you can use this with circle but not with Arc ?

Comment: yes, you can use it with arc too